# How to Manage Cordova/PhoneGap jQuery Mobile iOS WebApp Ongoing Update and Apple Review Process?

Tags: ios, cordova, configuration, appstore-approval

My Cordova iOS web app works with a production web site. The version of iOS webapp must match the version of the website for them to work properly.

Now I need to submit a version 2 of iOS webapp to Apple for review. I do have a staging website of version 2.

I have two options:

> 1. summit webapp pointing to staging server for Apple Review. If approved, change it to point to production server and submit it again with note indicating only changes made and hope for quick approval. Then I update production website to version 2  and  promote the approved version iOS webapp to iTune appstore.
> 2. Find some way to save SERVER_URL setting outside the iOS webapp (in html5 cache, etc) and let webapp to read this setting before running  and ask Apple reviewer to change this setting to STAGING_SERVER_URL before testing.

I don't like either. Maybe I am missing some other better approaches. I am hoping some guru can point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: decouple your app and the backend. why is it, that your webapp needs to match the version on the backend server?

Comment: They work hand in glove as newer version of mobile app client makes ajax call to server on newly available JSON service.

Comment: a better approach would be decoupling app and backend. implement a versioned API.